# Passing variables to another MATLAB version

Tags: matlab, 32bit-64bit

I have to work with an old fashioned program and I have to extract the data using a 32 bit MATLAB. After extracting the data, I will do some heavy processing on it. To speed up the processing, I'd like to use MATLAB 64 bit instead of 32.
How can I transfer the data from MATLAB 32 to 64 without saving and loading? Any other faster way?

Thanks,
Mina

Comment: Why do you believe that transferring to 64-bit MATLAB will magically make your processing faster?  What rationale or evidence did you discover or conclude that this is the course of action you need to pursue?  Did you profile your current code to see if there are other factors that are slowing down your execution time that isn't related to 32-/64-bit architecture?  I sincerely doubt that changing architecture will magically make your code faster.  It has something to do with what is being done in your current code.  That being said, please include a small code snippet illustrating your point.

Comment: What kind of data? For a complex data structure you may need something better, but if it's just a big array of numbers a simple tcp connection should do it: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/05/27/transferring-data-between-two-computers-using-matlab/

Answer (score 0):

You can use memmapfile to share the data via memory.